# Latching interval timer with positive trigger

Tags: 555, trigger, latching

Can I create a latching interval timer circuit with a 555 chip using a positive trigger (which is not pulsed but remains high during the timing interval and afterwards) without retriggering the timer? The timing interval would only be re-triggered if the positive trigger went low before returning to high.

Comment: So you want a one-shot that is only triggerable by a rising edge and not a level condition and that cannot be retriggered **during** a prior, triggered timing interval but only by a rising edge ***after*** the interval has expired? In short, you want rising edges to be ***masked*** when the timing interval is still active?

Comment: Unlike a 555, a true monostable circuit uses positive feedback to assure that it cannot be retriggered while timing.  1.  Does your circuit have to use a 555?  2.  What is the power source?  3.  What does the output pulse drive?

Answer (score 0):

When used as a one-shot, the 555 is **non-retriggerable** when wired up in its normal 'monostable' way. So it already does what you're asking for.

Here's a 555 sim as a one-shot, showing the 555 internals ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgzCAMB0l3BWEDYCYyoOytQTgByaT74CMSAbACwibKTICmAtKaQFACG4q%20Iq1EFVQ0BNXMighS8eJNLQKS5StVIZsrjz6kKfYTV18JSBhtnhoYazdt2oaAjISQKuOFTap1syOwBO4JA0JEGGYBRSLnABYfyhYMHgEVHw7ADucaT4NBg6OVAZcQlJDH6ZCLzSeshVpLiohZlUVDoNtXwiZUWVnVQMvfwIkeVCrfz9Y318oy19A3XtfgBKcQyJNMyTZUIDUmXQCOyruJEiIKcgzDNSk6b7h7GX55fkjWaaAMYXkW8--MQHr5SA5IHgyJAXG4PF5TLBIBwAOb-VCA57nbqBQbeSLDTrDKTmPzkCBzIa4qo46T8SRHElTap8QZGakQAZFV6VbTSLl%20ZEbcAFAX9G5%20AAeIAoYBB6AY2FE1iE1RAABMAJYAZ0%20AAtOP5EYwADoagAUmAAlOwJaizm5%20JgkFhGoZIgAXfxqxEG-zGk2oS0S7ISUgte06Kh0F0gV3a-yMDXagD2ABsVb6KAGAYZMJ1ML8yErdCBPomAHbulO%20hCW13IGpUihwcmEhwITBgFwYCIEBCkazvRSQax9zBUMAkBAIFqGJsqxgAM04AFdk67YgLsrkkiIbtFRhuUhuCvvt%20MBbwZkU8hM%20OfxifDAUutJjz1QyzmTU-ABJBmhMm6DsMBIEczTjP%204z3laQgIPoAyhmOhaRMsACiADKKEACqlr6VCWpkArWJEjbrCkowkckxFNk6TSStRkxuGc2xFIxEwMKxZKjJyjRFn8oy8VyRacUUQnjBxUEAEbxDQmAghQ2TgC4tFTi6fCsSyD4gAkoahH4gRgDp%20hFrp0i%20NBUo8W2tBNoBSEgImS6ugADo5vpgJm6BIOO8RGXZABqADCAUmvgHmKmARD8O0EWksqADiAByAAivqkPhcRERlr5gW0zrjKQea0QKDCcbRpVklBzTGfo4GXqikbnGIQiNZcNAYZh7D1c1qndQCJUgKh7WdZAdDqTU7a-DUNAAPIAKodTljK9RpRRkk1Bj8II%206UvgZjtLw3QADLSPtu1LQdLaLsmGqMJIfiJtIUYlZAuASDA5AUN4oLwLgebDF9DA8bk7APZOyrPa932kDgI1DtDcKyL9FD-eoNJg2AIPIE9uyQzAcDQ-VcMA-CcBIyj1KNFO4CYwSRYQ29JMjZ9uBgLgVAINKxOI39n2OmjkQY0AA)):

[image]

First, know that the 555 TRIG pin is **active low**. If you need active high you will need to invert your trigger source.

How it works:

- (1) Not triggered: DISCH is turned on, holding the capacitor low.
- (2) TRIG going low: sets the internal flip-flop, releasing DISCH and letting the capacitor charge (internal 'SET' node goes high)
- (3) Capacitor reaches THRESH voltage: the flip-flop is reset (internal 'RESET' node goes high)

Note that during (2), the timing cycle, OUT is high, forcing that lower NOR to low, and turning off DISCH. **This inhibits any further activity on TRIG.**  It has to time out first before it can see activity on TRIG again. Like I said, non-retriggerable.

Try toggling the TRIG input quickly. You'll see that it fires on only the first low-going edge and ignores further toggles until the end of its timing cycle.

Also, try just leaving TRIG low. You'll see that at the end of the timing cycle, the timer will not fire again until you bring TRIG high (discharging the cap and releasing RESET), then low again (setting the flop and starting the timing cycle.)